# Creating new layout using arcpy.mp in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts

Our team uses `arcpy.mp` to automate production of large volumes of maps. We have created an ArcGIS Pro project which contains several commonly-used map templates (as layout objects), such that team members can use python scripts to select one of the templates in the project and create maps quickly. Since we have only been able to use `arcpy.mp` to modify existing layouts in the project, we need to use base python to copy the entire project before editing the templates.

What we would *like* to do is copy a layout template, create a new layout, and then modify that new layout without needing to copy the entire project directory. I can't find any functionality in `arcpy` to create new layouts.

Is there a way to make new layouts from python scripts?

Comment: Templates as Layout files (.pagx) then `ArcGISProject.importDocument` https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm

Comment: @user2856 thanks very much for your answer. Would you suggest the workflow of create new project -> import existing templates? If so, it seems simpler to stick with the existing solution of just copying the project - no need to import anything.

Comment: I suggested that because you asked about layout templates instead of copying the project.